# Table with list of database administrators in IBM i

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I want a list of users on an IBMi Machine who have access to create RCAC permissions (Create Mask, Row permission etc). Is this data stored in any table?

Answer (score 1):

Not just in one table but I think this is a good start to list users with [administative authority](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=concepts-authorization-privileges-object-ownership#rbafzauthown__rbafzsecadm)

```
SELECT
  distinct AUTHORIZATION_NAME
FROM QSYS2.USER_INFO cross
  join lateral (select * from table(systools.split(SPECIAL_AUTHORITIES,' '))) a
where element in ('*SECADM','*ALLOBJ')
union
SELECT
  user_name
FROM qsys2.function_usage
where function_id = 'QIBM_DB_SECADM'
  and usage = 'ALLOWED'
```

Comment: Maybe members of groups are missing